# Using an uninitialised variable in a constructor

Tags: java

So I have a rather simple piece of code:

```
    Soldier Horseman = new Soldier("Horseman",Archer, 20);
    Soldier Spearman = new Soldier("Spearman",Horseman, 10);
    Soldier Archer = new Soldier("Archer",Spearman, 10);
```

Where the constructor for soldier takes the arguments

```
    Soldier(String name, Soldier target, double range)
```

The target is then used to calculate distance between the two in a method.

```
public double DistanceCalculation() {
    distanceToTarget = ((Math.pow((soldierPosition[0] - soldierTarget.soldierPosition[0]), 2)) + Math.pow((soldierPosition[1] - soldierTarget.soldierPosition[1]), 2));
    return distanceToTarget;
```

However, when I try to create this code, the top most soldier cannot be created because its target doesnt exist yet. I tried using String instead of Soldier in the constructor, but then I cannot figure out how to convert string into Soldier so that the SoldierTarget.soldierPosition works. Any ideas?

Comment: when do you callDistanceCalculation()

Comment: In another method that compares the three soldiers distances to their target

Comment: On a side note, please use camelCase (first letter lowercase) for objects / variables - it's Java convention and so easier to read for most of us.

Comment: Why does a Soldier need a target immediately upon creation? Why not have a method in `Soldier` like `setTarget(Soldier target)` that targets a particular Soldier object and remove `target` from the constructor? Seems your design might need a little revision.

Comment: You should be able to make `target` a different type then the soldier itself.

Comment: @tnw You know when you think about a solution for so long that the simplest solution completely escapes you? Thank you, this solves what I need to do.

Comment: @Seraphim Quite welcome

Comment: you may want to create a Target interface and use that instead of Soldier directly. What if you want to shoot at a building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the target in the constructor. Set it in another method:

```
Soldier target;
Soldier(String name,double range) {
  // etc
}
public void setTarget( Soldier s ) {
   target = s;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Soldier horseman = new Soldier("Horseman", 20);
Soldier spearman = new Soldier("Spearman", 10);
Soldier archer = new Soldier("Archer", 10);

horseman.setTarget(archer);
spearman.setTarget( horseman );
archer.setTarget(spearman);
```

This way each soldier knows about his current target. Then if (for example) horseman vanquishes the archer, you can just call `horseman.setTarget(spearman)` to set a new target.
I was assuming range was the soldier's maximum attack range, but if it is the distance to the target it should not be set in the constructor either.

Comment: Although I find Pauls anwser more useful in the long term, this is much simpler for what I need right now, so I am accepting you

Answer (score 4):

It may be a better idea to store the information about targets in a separate data structure, e.g. a `HashMap<Soldier, Soldier>`. Then you can make `Soldier` immutable, and all the circularity problems disappear.

```
Soldier horseman = new Soldier("Horseman", 20);
Soldier spearman = new Soldier("Spearman", 10);
Soldier archer = new Soldier("Archer", 10);
Map<Soldier, Soldier> targets = new HashMap<>();
targets.put(horseman, archer);
targets.put(archer, spearman);
targets.put(spearman, horseman);
```

Comment: I really like this solution, although I need to read up on how maps work because Ive never used them. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. It's a good idea to learn about maps anyway. `HashMap` is a very popular class.

Answer (score 2):

You could create another constructor (in addition to your already existing one):

```
Soldier(String name, double range)
```

and then in your `DistanceCalculation` method, perform a `hasTarget()` check.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
Soldier Horseman = null;
Soldier Spearman = null;
Soldier Archer = null;
Horseman = new Soldier("Horseman",Archer, 20);
Spearman = new Soldier("Spearman",Horseman, 10);
Archer = new Soldier("Archer",Spearman, 10);
```

Comment: This compiles, but you're still passing `null` into your constructor.  Changing your local variables later to be non-null won't change the value you already passed into the previous constructor.

Comment: That will *compile*, but `Horseman` won't have the reference to `Archer`, which I believe is the intent.